# Photoshop Elements 9 VS Paintshop Photo Pro X3 For Web Design

Tags: web-development, photoshop

I need a good image creation program for web design.

I have downloaded both Elements 9 and Paintshop X3. So far I have found them both to be great programs. X3 seems like it has a lot of features, Elements seems like it's quite easy and stable to use.

I think I'm going to go with Elements, but I wanted to get other opinions. Which program do you guys like better overall? What things do you think they lack for image creation/editing pertaining to web design, or what features do they have that are great for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using Photoshop Elements over the other. It has certainly good selections flexibility, and is very useful. Is not photoshop, but is quite good, and very well priced. IMHO Elements has better tools for the "deep level" work. The toys or "magical" features (ie, red eyes removing) are always things that can be done with strong basic features, if they are well implemented. IE, selections, etc. Which is pretty solid in Elements, specially at that price. Remember though that Elements hasn't got the CMYK printing features of Photoshop, but you are not needing that, I guess.

For certain extra feature you might need one day or another, I'd recomend to have always installed a recent version of Gimp, it's becoming quite powerful. Even while I would prefer Elements GUI for the everyday work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Photoshop (not Elements) for years. It is a fantastic program. Recently though, I have been using PS Elements. I love it.

It's cheaper. It does every thing that I need in order to create simple graphics and edit photos. It also lets me create the image types I need, such as gif, jpg, and png. So far I have found no downsides.

I also have a PC running Ubuntu, so Adobe products are out of the question. I've been using GIMP and InkScape. They are free, but a little cumbersome to move around in. On my windows laptop I have also used paint.net. It's free and lets me do some intermediate design and images.

I think that you can't go wrong with PS Elements, but maybe give some opensource programs a try too. I have never tried Paintshop.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any experience with Elements or Paintshop...Luckily I'm able to have the full Adobe CS package at home as well as at my office for my full-time job, otherwise I wouldn't have a full version of Photoshop to work with.

Gimp is another good option, but to me the UI is complicated to learn.

A great free solution I've used in the past, and still do from time to time when making small edits is [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET). It's easy to use and does almost everything that Photoshop can.